# How to control the name of a saved variable from linear regression in SPSS?

Tags: spss

When I run a multiple linear regression in SPSS, I want to save Mahalanobis distance.
By default when I do this, SPSS adds a variable called `MAH_1` to the data frame.
I would like to indicate using syntax what that variable should be called. This would help make any example more reproducible if this variable were to be used in a subsequent analysis.

**How do you control the name of the variable generated by linear regression in SPSS?**

For example, here is some sample syntax:

```
REGRESSION
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA
  /DEPENDENT id
  /METHOD=ENTER IV1 IV2 IV3 IV4
  /SAVE MAHAL.
```

Is there some syntax which follows the `MAHAL` command which allows you to specify the name of the generated variable?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to seemingly answer the question with a little experimentation.

Writing the preferred name in parentheses after the saved object name generates the saved object with the preferred name. I.e., changing `MAHAL` to `MAHAL(FOO)`, means that the saved values of Mahalanobis distance are now called `foo` instead of the default `MAH_1`.

```
REGRESSION
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA
  /DEPENDENT id
  /METHOD=ENTER IV1 IV2 IV3 IV4
  /SAVE MAHAL(foo).
```

And the section of the Help file for the [save option in the regression command elaborates](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/topic/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_regression_save.htm).